# nginx http server_names_hash_bucket_size

Tags: nginx, git

I recently installed GitLab & nginx on my server. All went through well, however, I am having problem in `server_names_hash_bucket_size` & `server_names_hash_max_size`. I need to increase it, but then I am confused with the nginx documentation. I don't know where to put the http {} that contains the two. My config is as below:

```
http {
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
  server_names_hash_max_size 512;
}

server {
  listen *:80;         # e.g., listen 192.168.1.1:80; In most cases *:80 is a good idea
  server_name gitkeeper.adtaco.com;     # e.g., server_name source.example.com;
  server_tokens off;     # don't show the version number, a security best practice
  root /home/git/gitlab/public;

  # individual nginx logs for this gitlab vhost
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  location / {
    # serve static files from defined root folder;.
    # @gitlab is a named location for the upstream fallback, see below
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
  }

  # if a file, which is not found in the root folder is requested,
  # then the proxy pass the request to the upsteam (gitlab unicorn)
  location @gitlab {
    proxy_read_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_connect_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab;
  }
}
```

When I try to restart nginx, it will not output anything. I see this through `/var/log/nginx.error.log` and displays this error ***"http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/gitlab:***

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If this is a setup like Debian does, with `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` included from `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` like this:

```
http {
    ...
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

you already are in a `http {}` stanza and could write your `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/gitlab` like this:

```
server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
server_names_hash_max_size 512;

server {
  listen *:80;         # e.g., listen 192.168.1.1:80; In most cases *:80 is a good idea
  server_name gitkeeper.adtaco.com;     # e.g., server_name source.example.com;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Cool! That should do it. However, I received a 502 Bad Gateway response.

Comment: @LeandroGarcia post logs? just "502" isn't going to explain itself :)

Answer (score 0):

When you restart nginx, you may see this error:

nginx: [emerg] could not build server_names_hash, you should increase server_names_hash_bucket_size: 64

Check the full error by running:

sudo nginx -t

You can resolve the error, by adding this line to nginx.conf in the http block.

after -> server_tokens off;

server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;